# Make a form run a javascript when ENTER is pressed or its button is pressed, without submitting

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form with just one field:

```
  <form id="formCode" onsubmit="return saveCode()" />
    <label for="fcode">Type Code:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="fcode" name="fcode" autofocus /><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit – Enviar" onclick="return saveCode()" />
  </form>
```

This is the Javascript I have on the page:

```
 document.addEventListener("keydown", function(inEvent){
    if (inEvent.keyCode == 13) { // enter
      if (document.getElementById("fcode").value === "") { return; }  // do nothing
      saveCodeCode();
      return false;
    }
  });

  function saveCode() {
    var codeField = document.getElementById("fcode");
    var value = codeField.value;
    if (value === "") { return false; }
    saveValue(value);
    codeField.value = "Submitted";
    return false;
  }
```

What happens right now is this: the form is always submitted.

I want this behavior:

1. the user is inside the textfield and types the code
2. at this point, I want the user to be able to press ENTER and run `saveCode()` or
3. press the submit button and also run `saveCode`.
4. I don't want this form to be submitted, just run the javascript method.
5. if the field is empty I want nothing to be done.

Comment: That `onsubmit` handler should be all you need. Try using `event.preventDefault` instead of returning `false`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Bergi said earlier the best way to do this is to use `event.preventDefault()`. So **in order to achieve this you need some modification, first of all, it is better to set your event listener to the specific `input`**, then your remaining code for listening to the event should work fine. Then **you need to use `event.preventDefault()` inside your `saveCode()` (And also after catching enter event) to prevent submitting form**, but to make `event` work as expected you need to avoid using return in your `onclick` (<s>`return saveCode()`</s>) method to allow event passing to the function automatically.

### UPDATE

Since there were some bugs in the previous method, I just add some modifications to it. Due to the `saveCode()` reference error I moved above of all of its usage to prevent such a thing, then I removed `onclick` events (They are not recommended at all it JS anymore) and then add an event listener for submitting event instead.

So your final code should be something like this (If `saveValue()` is existed and work as well):

```js
var codeField = document.getElementById("fcode");

function saveCode() {
  console.log("saveCode is running!");
  saveValue(value);
  codeField.value = "Submitted";
  return false;
}

document
  .getElementById("fcode")
  .addEventListener("keydown", function(inEvent) {
    if (inEvent.keyCode == 13) {
      // enter
      inEvent.preventDefault();
      if (this.value === "") {
        return false;
      } // do nothing
      saveCode();
      return false;
    }
  });

document
  .getElementById("formCode")
  .addEventListener("submit", function(inEvent) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var value = codeField.value;
    if (value === "") {
      return false;
    }
    saveCode();
  });
```

```html
<form id="formCode">
  <label for="fcode">Type Code:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="fcode" name="fcode" autofocus /><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit – Enviar" />
</form>
```

Comment: Very strange. I test your code here it works, I copy your code to my page, it does not!

Comment: I did copy paste from here and my code... let me triple check

Comment: With this second `preventDefault()` added my form is acting like this: (1) empty field, enter, nothing happens, this is ok. (2) field not empty, enter, form not submitted, saveCode not running. (3) field empty or not empty, submit button pressed, form is submitting (not good)

Comment: do I still need to return false?

Comment: 1/10th of a second before the form is submited I see this on console: "Reference error: cannot find variable saveCode"...... variale?

Comment: ah, and when the button is pressed `saveCode()` is called twice. To confirm I added a second method called `saveCode2()` and add this method to onSubmit and the other one to onClick.

Comment: @DuckDucking Sorry for bothering, so I just modified my last code a bit. To prevent reference error it's better to move your `saveCode()` above all other depending elements. Then I just remove the `onclick` method from submitting `input` and `form` and instead of them just add another event listener to listen for submitting events. I just test it, and it passed all the listed issues. So check it again and let me know about it.

Comment: AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHAAAAAAAAAAAA! Now it is woking perfectly! **THANKS!**

Comment: Thanks for your patience, haha. Another note to be considered is, is better to define `var codeField = document.getElementById("fcode");` in your global scope and then use the assigned value `codeField` in your other methods. Just like my latest update.

Answer (score 0):

The problem it's you try to call `saveValue(value)` function but this is undefined. So, false is never returned. Remove `saveValue(value)` or define it and try again, this work.

And you don't need to use `return` in `onsubmit`, just write `onsubmit="saveCode()"`

Answer (score -2):

All buttons inside the form are programmed to automatically submit the form (or type=submit), which means there are two ways to do this:

1) `<button onclick="saveCode()"></button>` outside the form 
2) `<button type=button></button>` inside the form